# prevent two bootstrap container overlap eachother.?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Updated with relative position.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<style>

@media (max-width: 768px) {
.first {
 position: static;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 4;
 border: 3px solid red;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #280489 0%, #e24301 100%);
 border-image-slice: 1;
 height: auto;
 padding: 52px 60px 64px 49px;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
}
.second {
 position: static;
 width: 600px;
 height: 400px;
 right: 0px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
.first {
 position: static;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 4;
 border: 3px solid red;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #280489 0%, #e24301 100%);
 border-image-slice: 1;
 height: auto;
 padding: 52px 60px 64px 49px;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
}
.second {
 position: static;
 width: 600px;
 height: 400px;
 right: 0px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.first {
 position: static;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 4;
 border: 3px solid red;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #280489 0%, #e24301 100%);
 border-image-slice: 1;
 height: auto;
 padding: 52px 60px 64px 49px;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
}
.second {
 position: static;
 width: 499px;
 height: 100px;
 right: 0px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
.first {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 4;
 border: 3px solid red;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #280489 0%, #e24301 100%);
 border-image-slice: 1;
 height: auto;
 padding: 52px 60px 64px 49px;
 top: 142px;
 left: 106px;
}
.second {
 position: absolute;
 width: 600px;
 height: 400px;
 right: 45px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.first {
 position: relative;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 4;
 border: 3px solid red;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #280489 0%, #e24301 100%);
 border-image-slice: 1;
 height: auto;
 padding: 52px 60px 64px 49px;
 top: 142px;
 left: 106px;
 clear: both;
}
.second {
 position: relative;
 width: 600px;
 height: 400px;
 right: -422px;
clear: both;
top: -294px;
}
}
.zero-padding {
 padding: 0px !important;
}

@mixin clearfix() {
  &::after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
  }
}


.element {
  @include clearfix;
}
</style>

<!-- Our story Section Start -->
 
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center heading">
      <h1>OUR STORY</h1>
      <div class="smaller-border text-center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="container" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 first ">
      <p style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Sajaya Young Ladies was established under the name of Children Centers in 2004, and declared its independence in 2012, to focus on young ladies based on the vision of Her Highness Sheikha Jawaher bint Mohammad Al Qassimi.</p>
      <a class="gradient-btn gradient-color" style="padding: 10px;">More Details</a> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 second"> <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gdt5cK/Image_1.jpg" class="img img-responsive" alt="image" > </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end -->
 
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
 
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center heading">
      <h1>Upcoming Activities</h1>
      <div class="smaller-border text-center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
  <!-- Our story Section Start -->
<div class="container" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 first zero-padding">
      <p style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Sajaya Young Ladies was established under the name of Children Centers in 2004, and declared its independence in 2012, to focus on young ladies based on the vision of Her Highness Sheikha Jawaher bint Mohammad Al Qassimi.</p>
      <a class="gradient-btn gradient-color" style="padding: 10px;">More Details</a> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 second"> <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gdt5cK/Image_1.jpg" class="img img-responsive" alt="image" > </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end -->
```

I am stuck with overlapping even my both containers are separated still i could not figure out what making them look like this on lg and xl screen size. Here is my code snippet let me know what causing them to overlap with each other like this. How far i believe there is something happening wrong with positions but if i change position of any element it get all messed up.

Here is my  goal to achieve. 
[image]

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<style>

.smaller-border {
 border-bottom: 3px solid red;
 width: 100px;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #280489 0%, #e24301 100%);
 border-image-slice: 1;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 80px;
}
.gradient-color {
 background: linear-gradient(to left, #280489 20%, #e24301 100%);
 background-clip: text;
 text-fill-color: transparent;
 color: transparent;
 font-family: "HelveticaNeue";
 font-weight: bold;
}
.left-btn {
 float: left;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
.first {
 position: static;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 4;
 border: 3px solid red;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #280489 0%, #e24301 100%);
 border-image-slice: 1;
 height: auto;
 padding: 52px 60px 64px 49px;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
}
.second {
 position: static;
 width: 600px;
 height: 400px;
 right: 0px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
.first {
 position: static;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 4;
 border: 3px solid red;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #280489 0%, #e24301 100%);
 border-image-slice: 1;
 height: auto;
 padding: 52px 60px 64px 49px;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
}
.second {
 position: static;
 width: 600px;
 height: 400px;
 right: 0px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.first {
 position: static;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 4;
 border: 3px solid red;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #280489 0%, #e24301 100%);
 border-image-slice: 1;
 height: auto;
 padding: 52px 60px 64px 49px;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
}
.second {
 position: static;
 width: 499px;
 height: 100px;
 right: 0px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
.first {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 4;
 border: 3px solid red;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #280489 0%, #e24301 100%);
 border-image-slice: 1;
 height: auto;
 padding: 52px 60px 64px 49px;
 top: 142px;
 left: 106px;
}
.second {
 position: absolute;
 width: 600px;
 height: 400px;
 right: 45px;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.first {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 4;
 border: 3px solid red;
 border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #280489 0%, #e24301 100%);
 border-image-slice: 1;
 height: auto;
 padding: 52px 60px 64px 49px;
 top: 142px;
 left: 106px;
 clear: both;
}
.second {
 position: absolute;
 width: 600px;
 height: 400px;
 right: 163px;
 clear: both;
}
}
.zero-padding {
 padding: 0px !important;
}

@mixin clearfix() {
  &::after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
  }
}


.element {
  @include clearfix;
}

</style>

 <!-- Our story Section Start -->
<div class="container" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center heading">
      <h1>OUR STORY</h1>
      <div class="smaller-border text-center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 first ">
      <p style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Sajaya Young Ladies was established under the name of Children Centers in 2004, and declared its independence in 2012, to focus on young ladies based on the vision of Her Highness Sheikha Jawaher bint Mohammad Al Qassimi.</p>
      <a class="gradient-btn gradient-color" style="padding: 10px;">More Details</a> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 second"> <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gdt5cK/Image_1.jpg" class="img img-responsive" alt="image" > </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end -->
 
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
 
  <!-- Our story Section Start -->
<div class="container" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center heading">
      <h1>Upcoming Activities</h1>
      <div class="smaller-border text-center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 first zero-padding">
      <p style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Sajaya Young Ladies was established under the name of Children Centers in 2004, and declared its independence in 2012, to focus on young ladies based on the vision of Her Highness Sheikha Jawaher bint Mohammad Al Qassimi.</p>
      <a class="gradient-btn gradient-color" style="padding: 10px;">More Details</a> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 second"> <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gdt5cK/Image_1.jpg" class="img img-responsive" alt="image" > </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end -->
```

Comment: I didn't check all your CSS code but if with bootstrap you end up having overlapping container then you are using it wrong ... better rely on the documentation and built-in classes than trying to use complex CSS

Comment: I could not find any css regards absolute two columns i have used custom media to achieve it. it not that much complex then it seems.

Comment: and that absolute is creating the issue .. are you sure you need absolute? maybe describe the layout you want to achieve and you will get better way

Comment: what i want to achieve is to like seperate both containers from eachother regard absolute i will need it to combine two columns with eachother. which working perfectly untill it added same like container again.

Comment: I mean *what layout you want*. Actually *you* think that absolute position is need for your layout but probably not. I am pretty sure we can achieve what you want without absolute position and you will avoid the issue you had

Comment: I have edited my post with snapshot of what i want to design but i tried your solution well it separated two containers but now it like i will have to give each section separate css and headings are getting covered with added two code snippets i just changed postion from absolute to relative to updated snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180162/discussion-between-kamran-hassan-and-temani-afif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using some negative margin and without the need of absolute position.

Here is a simplified example based on your code (I removed extra visual styles to keep the most important code)

```css
.smaller-border {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #280489 0%, #e24301 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.left-btn {
  float: left;
}

.first p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 40px;
  margin-right: -100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 22;
  background: #fff;
}

.second img {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.zero-padding {
  padding: 0px !important;
}

@media all and (max-width:767px) {
  .first p {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Our story Section Start -->
<div class="container" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center heading">
      <h1>OUR STORY</h1>
      <div class="smaller-border text-center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 first ">
      <p style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Sajaya Young Ladies was established under the name of Children Centers in 2004, and declared its independence in 2012, to focus on young ladies based on the vision of Her Highness Sheikha Jawaher bint Mohammad Al Qassimi.</p>
      <a class="gradient-btn gradient-color" style="padding: 10px;">More Details</a> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 second"> <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gdt5cK/Image_1.jpg" class="img img-responsive" alt="image"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end -->

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<!-- Our story Section Start -->
<div class="container" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center heading">
      <h1>Upcoming Activities</h1>
      <div class="smaller-border text-center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 first zero-padding">
      <p style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Sajaya Young Ladies was established under the name of Children Centers in 2004, and declared its independence in 2012, to focus on young ladies based on the vision of Her Highness Sheikha Jawaher bint Mohammad Al Qassimi.</p>
      <a class="gradient-btn gradient-color" style="padding: 10px;">More Details</a> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 second"> <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gdt5cK/Image_1.jpg" class="img img-responsive" alt="image"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end -->
```

Comment: You are life saver. Thanks alot